# Volt.php files not auto-updating

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

While using the volt template the files ending with .volt would auto generate a volt.php file and if any changes were made to the volt file, the volt.php file would not be updated unless deleted manually for it to generate a new volt.php file. Is there a way for it to auto-update when changes were made?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wasn't. I don't think this has changed. You can however set `compileAlways` flag while in development, or set it depending on your app environment variable, if you use one. Read [this](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/550/disable-cache-vor-view-in-dev-environment) for more details.

```
$di->set('view', function(){
    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
    $view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');

        $view->registerEngines(array(
            '.volt' => function($view, $di) {
            $volt = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt($view, $di);
            $volt->setOptions(array(
              'compiledPath' => '../app/compiled/',
              'stat' => true,
              'compileAlways' => true  
            ));
            return $volt;
            }
        ));

    return $view;
});
```